# How can I load WordPress images from another url?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I tried these different solutions to load the images from the live website but it didn't work.

The website where I'm trying to load the images is a staging website. The live website has many large images so transferring them is not an option. Please note that domain is anonymized. Thank you for your help.

Can you tell me why these solutions don't work? You can also show me another solution if you want.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteRule ^/?website.com/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://www.website.de/wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,L]

#RedirectMatch 301 https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/(.*) https://www.website.de/wp-content/uploads/$1

#RewriteRule ^/website.com/wp-content/uploads/$ website.de/wp-content/uploads/

#RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/\d+/.*)$ https://www.website.de/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

#RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://www.website.de/wp-content/uploads/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Are you saying that image files stopped working after using RewriteRule or What exactly is your problem?

Comment: The external images are just not loading

Comment: If you are linking your image files from external sources then this is not an htaccess issue. Check your image file links to make sure they are working.

Comment: its not replacing the image url so it cant work

Comment: Why not run a database + codebase search and replace on your staging site to replace website.com with website.de? rather than having to use .htaccess redirects

Comment: because htaccess is not permanent and one change for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can also show me another solution if you want.

So instead of explaining why your rules aren't working I'll go with your request and share here what works for me:

**1.** Create a new .htaccess file and add the following rules to it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Remember to change `https://www.example.com/` with your actual domain name (the production one.)

**2.** Place this .htaccess file in your localhost / staging site's `/wp-content/uploads` folder.

**3.** Profit!

Basically this tells the server that if the requested file can't be found then redirect the current request to the specified URI.